# I want to include non plain TeX code via \input to plain Tex

Tags: input, opmac

I'm using plain TeX with OPmac and want to add directly source code to my TeX source.

I have to extend firstly source code with `\begtt` and `\endtt` and only then I can use `\input source_code` to incude it to my TeX code.

Exist way, how to include external not formatted TeX code via `\input` without previous adjustment?

Comment: Isn't `\begtt...\endtt` meant for verbatim content in `opmac` only?

Comment: `\expandafter\begtt\input source_code` might work but there must be a way to input code an prettyprint it. If not, wipet may give an official answer of how to do that.

Comment: `\verbinput` might be what you are looking for. It's used like `\verbinput (-) source_code` to input the whole file, and `\verbinput (2-17) source_code` for just certain lines. (There's also options with `+`, just read the documentation.)

Comment: `\verbinput` is working for my need, thank you a lot @Manuel (I do not see, how to mark you answer as the solution, so I'm using reply via comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\verbinput` might be what you are looking for. It's used like `\verbinput (-) source_code` to input the whole file, and `\verbinput (2-17) source_code` for just certain lines. (There's also options with `+`, just read the documentation.)